# i3-status freezes

Tags: debian, i3, x2go

I'm running i3 windows manager on Debian 10 and I'm connecting to the computer through X2go as I'm working at home at the moment.

Since the upgrade from Debian 9 to Debian 10 (done recently) the i3-status bar freezes and I have to 'reload' i3 which is a slight pain.

Here is my .i3status.conf

```
general {
    interval        = 1
    colors          = true
    color_good      = '#88b090'
    color_degraded  = '#ccdc90'
    color_bad       = '#e89393'
}

# order += "volume master"
# order += "disk /"
# order += "disk /home"
# order += "disk /media/data"
# order += "ethernet br0"
# order += "cpu_temperature 0"
# order += "memory"
# order += "load"
order += "tztime local"

# ethernet br0 {
#     #if you use %speed, i3status requires root privileges
#     format_up = "%ip (%speed)"
#     format_down = ""
# }

tztime local {
    format = "%A %e.%B %H:%M:%S"
}

# load {
#     format = "%1min"
# }

# cpu_usage {
#     format = "%usage"
# }

# cpu_temperature 0 {
#   format = "%degrees°C"
# }

# disk "/" {
#   format = "/ %avail"
#   prefix_type = custom
# }

# disk "/home" {
#   format = "/home %avail"
#   prefix_type = custom
# }

# disk "/media/data" {
#   format = "/media/data %avail"
#   prefix_type = custom
# }

# volume master {
#     format = "VOL: %volume "
#     format_muted = "MUTE "
#     device = "default"
#     mixer = "Master"
#     mixer_idx = 0
# }
```

When it freezes the time isn't moving but I can still see the date and time just in a frozen state.

I've tried running i3status in a terminal and it's been running fine for a few weeks non-stop;

Here is the output (note this is when I had all my settings on in my config and I haven't had to restart it since);

```
 ~ % i3status
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: auto-detected "term"
/ 6.5 GB | /home 103.1 GB | /media/data 543.9 GB | 4.29 | Monday 28.September 09:10:16
```

I cannot replicate the problem but I think it might have something to do with when I exit X2go. When I exit X2go I keep the session running in the background, then the next day I connect to it. Now when it's in this state is when it typically freezes. Maybe i3-status doesn't like to be in an X2go session which has been detached but still running.

**Update**

After running the i3status.sh script it failed when I disconnected X2go shortly after work and I get the error;

```
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: falling back to "none"
```

I've added the following to my config -> general area to test

```
    output_format = "i3bar"
```

**Update: Forced fail**

Just managed to force it to fail, by exiting the X2go remote session (but keeping it going in the background), making a coffee (5minutes) and then rejoining the X2go session.

It still fails with output_format forced to i3bar. I don't get any error in i3status-err.log now.

I have to hit ++r to get it started again.

Comment: I have the very similar issue. When i lock my computer using i3lock and come back the next day, i3status is frozen. By the time it looks like it happens shortly after I lock the computer. Also the i3status process is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the status bar freezes it is likely that the process has crashed and exited. You should check if `i3status` is running when the issue happens again.

You could also wrap `i3status` with your own script to troubleshoot the problem.

In your i3 `config` file replace the `status_command` with your own script:

```
# status_command i3status -c ~/.config/i3/i3status
status_command /home/YOURUSER/.config/i3/i3status.sh
```

Create `~/.config/i3/i3status.sh` (and chmod +x):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) started >> /tmp/i3status.log
while :
do
    i3status 2> /tmp/i3status-err.log | while :
    do
        read line
        echo "$line"
        touch /tmp/i3status-last-seen.log
    done
    echo $(date) restarted >> /tmp/i3status.log
done
```

Or, if it's a bug of i3status, try this alternative:

https://github.com/altdesktop/i3-dstatus

Comment: Ok I'll test with this. It happens pretty much every day after I exit X2go but keep the session going, then when I reattach it's frozen. So should be able to tell pretty quickly.

Comment: This script isn't restarting the status bar automatically. As in the eyes of i3status it's not failing, it thinks it's still working!

Comment: I've updated the script to restart - you didn't say if the script exited in your update.

Comment: It didn't seem to exit the script. There was nothing in the i3status.log file and nothing in the err log either.

Comment: You could try to report it as a bug to the project.

Comment: Just came across https://github.com/altdesktop/i3-dstatus ...

Comment: Thanks laktak I'll give it a go, sounds like it may fix my problem

Comment: After a reboot and using your script it hasn't missed a beat. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem.  In my case, it was hanging on a `disk {` clause for an inaccessible NFS mount.  I removed that clause from `~/.config/i3status/config`, and that fixed it.